# How to submit form with react-query

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-query, mutation

I have following code

```
const useCreateSupplier = (createSupplierCommand: CreateSupplierCommand) => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: () =>
      axiosClient
        .post("/supplier", { createSupplierCommand })
        .then((res: AxiosResponse) => res.data),
    onSuccess: async () => {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [queries.get_suppliers],
      });
    },
  });
};
```

```
const CreateSupplierForm = () => {
  const useSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    useCreateSupplier({ name: "x", website: "xxx" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form className="row mt-3 mb-4" onSubmit={useSubmit}>
        <div className="col-auto">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="name" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-auto">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="website" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

but the page render following error

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:

How can I call mutation after the form is submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you read up on what hooks are and how to use them.

`useSubmit` is not a hook and therefore it shouldn't start with the word `use`. I'll call it `onSubmit` instead.

As the message says hooks (like `useCreateSupplier`) need to be called in the function body, so we move it there.

[According to the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useMutation), `useMutation` returns an object, and to actually trigger the API call we need to call `mutate` (or `mutateAsync`) of that object.

```js
const CreateSupplierForm = () => {
   const mutation = useCreateSupplier({ name: 'x', website: 'xxx' });

   const onSubmit = () => {
       mutation.mutate()
   }

   return (
       <>
           <form className="row mt-3 mb-4" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
               <div className="col-auto">
                   <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="name" />
               </div>
               <div className="col-auto">
                   <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="website" />
               </div>
               <div className="col-auto d-flex align-items-center">
                   <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
               </div>
           </form>
       </>)
}
```

Apart from this, to call the form with your input, you will need to do some addional changes, e.g. storing the input in some kind of state. [Here's some reading](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-forms) on how to combine forms with Tanstack Query (React Query).